# Load Adserver Script with document write async / defer or after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I work on a customer website. An adserver script is very slow, but can't be edited. Inside of the script are some document write pieces and other scripts are included.

To improve page speed, the script should be "**defer**", "**async**" or "**load after page is finished**". The script can't be placed at the bottom.

I tried many solutions, but none have worked. Everything I tried had the result that the script doesn't load any more. (customer afid removed for examples)

**What I did:**

**1.** **Jquery document ready / get script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("http://www35.glam.com/gad/glamadapt_jsapi.act?afid=");
});
```

**2. Java Script bind**

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www35.glam.com/gad/glamadapt_jsapi.act?afid="></script>
    <script>
)};
```

**3. Add defer or async**

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="http://www35.glam.com/gad/glamadapt_jsapi.act?afid="></script>
<script>

<script defer type="text/javascript" src="http://www35.glam.com/gad/glamadapt_jsapi.act?afid="></script>
<script>
```

**4. Jquery lazy load**

```
http://jqueryad.web2ajax.fr/
```

Comment: I think **load after page is finished** is the best way to do with this. Ad isnot main part on page so can render lastly.

Comment: I assumed you meant that you had removed the afid for the examples, rather than you meaning that the techniques you tried didn't send them. Also, your example code contains too many opening script tags in 2 and 3, were they just copy/paste errors?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of your current script with some random `afid`?

Answer (score 0):

You could load the adserver script in a friendly IFrame.

Something like that:

```
<script>
(function(d){
  var iframe = d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('iframe')),
  doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

  // style the iframe with some CSS
  iframe.style.cssText = "position:absolute;width:200px;height:100px;left:0px;";

  doc.open().write('<body onload="' + 
  'var d = document;d.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].' + 
  'appendChild(d.createElement(\'script\')).src' + 
  '=\'\/path\/to\/file\'">');

  doc.close(); //iframe onload event happens

  })(document);
</script>
```